# Javascript dot notation to retrieve certain element on an object

Tags: javascript, ibm-datapower, apic

On IBM API Connect's GatewayScript, I'm trying to write a JS script to get object value from the following request payload:

```
{"number": "1234",
"type": "type1",
"someKey": "SomeValue"}
```

I'm using the following code, but getting a `NULL`:

```
var apim = require('apim');
var RequestBody = apim.getvariable('request.body');
var result = RequestBody.number;

apim.setvariable('message.body', result);
```

On APIC's gatewayscript, it's essentially doing a dot notation to get that key/value (`"someVal": "1234"`), but it's turning out to be `NULL`...
When I try to get the "`var result`" I do get all the payload... I just cannot get 1 of the value from the object where key is number = 1234.

Anyone have any ideas?

P.s. what I'm really asking is, if I wanted to get the output value of "`1234`" from request below:

```
var RequestBody = {"someVal": "1234"}
```

I think I would just to a dot notation of `RequestBody.someVal`, yes?

Thank you.

Comment: `var result = vRequestBody.someVal;` - was that really supposed to be `vRequestBody` there? Is this not supposed to refer to `RequestBody` from the previous line?

Comment: @CBroe you're right... that's not in my actual code... I just goofed on the sample here.
I've updated and it should be referencing RequestBody var and not vRequestBody.

Comment: you are getting null or undefined?

Comment: @marzzy it's responding with "null":

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks ok but you might have two issues...

First check that the Request Body actually is posted correctly and that the JSON is what you expect.

Secondly check that the Request Body is in fact JSON and not String. You can do this by:

```
const requestBody = apim.getvariable('request.body');
const jsonBody = typeof requestBody === 'string' ? JSON.parse(requestBody) : requestBody;

const result = jsonBody.number;
```

Comment: Yes... thank you @anders that was correct... I parsed it like the following, and it took:


JSON.parse(requestBody).someVal